# Why is python giving me an error for improper indentation when my indentation is correct?

Tags: python, indentation

This is the error message I got:

```sh
 File "main.py", line 15
   while True:
             ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

This is my full code:

```py
import wikipedia
from colorama import Fore, Style, Back
y = input("tell me what you want ")
z = int(input("how many sentences "))
try:
    text = wikipedia.summary(y, sentences=z)
    print('')
    print("---Text---")
    print(text)
    print("----------")
    print(len(text.split()),"words.")   
except:
    print(Fore.RED + "ERROR)
    while True:
        print("\a")
```

Can you please explain why this is happening? I am using the Repl online ide.

The answer to this is that I was mixing up tabs and spaces. You shouldn't use both because this error can happen.

Comment: You've mixed tabs and spaces. Don't do that. This is what happens when you do.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.   The posted code fails on the `except`, as that is not legal by itself.  When I add a `try` block in front, the `except` clause works as expected.

Comment: full code: ```import wikipedia
from colorama import Fore, Style, Back
y = input("tell me what you want ")
z = int(input("how many sentences "))
try:
 text = wikipedia.summary(y, sentences=z)
 print('')
 print("---Text---")
 print(text)
 print("----------")
 print(len(text.split()),"words.") 
except:
 print(Fore.RED + "ERROR")
    while True:
     print("\b")
     ```

Comment: Jon, if you use your mouse to mark the text in that previous comment, you'll see most have a space followed by tabs (and I'm assuming the space is simply an artifact of the cut'n'paste into the comment). However, it all spaces before the `while true` and space/tab/spaces before the final print. Config your editor to use four spaces as per PEP8 and your problem will be solved.

Comment: And, in future, you can do something like: `( grep '^ +\t' x.py ; grep '^\t+ ' x.py ) | wc -l` to detect any lines mixing tabs and spaces at the start. It if gives anything other than zero, you need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While coding in python, it's super important to pay attention to the way you indent. Of course you can either use tab or space, but always make sure you stick with one of them and not mixing them together.

Seems like you haven't done it this time. Delete the indentations and reindent them. Should work fine.